# Potential mix-up of job applications: Engineer - Data Scientist

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow-jobs

My job application is now **linked to a different position.**

I had applied for (I think) this position
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104198/full-stack-net-c-sharp-engineer-autoloop
(Or one very similar to it)

You can see in the screen-cap below that it shows that the title was **Full Stack .Net/C# Engineer** but under "For" it lists **Junior Data Scientist**

[image: Engineer, or Data Scientist?]

Indeed the company does have a posting for a data scientist
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/119044/junior-data-scientist-autoloop

On the company's Job's page, you can see both are listed
[image: Not the same job]
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/loop#jobs

I just want to make sure the company received the application for the correct position, most likely they updated the exiting position with the data scientist one, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: I think the author of the listing might have changed it from a C# Developer listing to a Data Scientist listing. Your application was for the same posting, but the posting changed to be a completely different job! We'll reach out to the customer and find out.

Comment: @Benjamin Hodgson I figured something like that happened. I appreciate you looking into it.