# Employers can update jobs, but applicants cannot update applications

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When searching for jobs and sorting by newest, I frequently see jobs listed as having been posted recently that I cannot apply for because I applied to the "same" job a long time ago.  For example, today, June 5, there is a job listed as posted "4d ago" for which I applied several weeks ago. Other examples abound:

[image: Job posting indicates that it is 26 days old but the user applied 54 weeks ago.]

Either applicants should be able to submit updated applications for these updated job descriptions, or the jobs returned by a search should be sorted by their original post date, not their edit date.

I updated this question in 2020 to report that while SO has failed to disincentivize recycling job postings, we could at least submit updated applications. **As of June 1, 2021, we are once again unable to submit updated applications.** Get it together, SO.

[image]

Comment: I don't know that I would label this a bug. This is pretty common. Stack Overflow only differs in that you *know* you aren't being considered again because the system prevents it as opposed to HR simply ignoring your new application because you've already applied within the last 30/60/whatever days.

Comment: @BSMP If HR has substantially changed the job description, then an updated application *should* be considered.  If the posting is substantially unchanged, then it should be sorted by its original post date.  Either way, the first page of results should not be cluttered with misleadingly-dated postings that you can't apply for.

Comment: @BSMP If I'm looking for jobs to apply for, showing me jobs you know I can't apply for isn't very helpful.  Whether that is common practice or not, it seems we can do better.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Sure, but this still probably [isn't a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337998/how-do-i-reapply-for-a-position-on-the-jobs-board):  *If the company used the same already-existing job listing then past applicants wouldn't be able to apply for 6 months.*

Comment: *If HR has substantially changed the job description, then an updated application should be considered.* Well, Stack Overflow can't force companies to actually re-consider you for a position. The best they could probably do is to not change the date on the listing if the company changes an existing job listing instead of creating a new one.

Comment: @BSMP the SO functionality is blocking something the company itself may not block.  Also, allowing a company to continually bump its posts with little edits is a kind of attention-grabbing behavior that we're well familiar with.  Both of these are SO bugs.

Comment: I remember seeing something like this on meta a few weeks ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337998/how-do-i-reapply-for-a-position-on-the-jobs-board

Comment: I see this sort of thing on sites all the time. Not just SO. I even had one on Monster that I couldn't apply to "because you applied to this job with this resume already" despite the fact that I'd uploaded that resume *less than two days prior.* There was no way it was the same one I'd previously applied with.

Comment: We're reviewing this now.

Comment: Is there an official answer to why this has gone unresolved for so long? It's ridiculous because I can update my application on every other job listing site, so that's why I've stopped using SO as a job website. I applied for a job 6 months ago and have updated my resume since then and I can't edit my application to that job. I tried going to their website but it just links back to SO.

Comment: SO Jobs is basically dead and worthless because of this issue. More than half of job listings matching my searches are recycled and cannot be applied for.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

So my answer to this, this is absolutely a **major defect**.

I am currently working at a company I found through SO Careers. I initially applied to them in February directly via SO. While being open to remote, the position still predominantly focused on fill local. After they were unable to do so locally, they updated/refreshed the job post in late March.

I was not able to reapply through SO. I instead had to go outside SO, find the company website and found a way to apply direct instead.

I am a success story of this failure.

If a company refreshes their post, applicants should be able to reapply. (Maybe with some very finite exclusion window say 7 days)

Comment: The limitation is probably intentional, to force companies to purchase a new listing when they have a new position to fill, rather than recycling the old already-paid one.  (Much the same way that question-banned users are often found editing their old questions into something entirely different, hoping for answers to their new problem and creating a huge mess since the old answers are still there)

Comment: @BenVoigt this position was definitely the same position. A separate question seems to be exactly the situation you mentioned of recycling a post to save money: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332744/potential-mix-up-of-job-applications-engineer-data-scientist

Comment: @BenVoigt Our pricing model is based on what we call "job slots", not job listings. Employers can write as many listings as they like: we only charge them for the jobs that are listed publicly on the job board at any given point in time. While we do try our hardest to encourage employers to write new listings rather than edit old ones (since it doesn't cost them anything), we can't really stop them from doing it. My hypothesis is that the current job listing form today is too long and difficult to use, so people would prefer to edit an existing job than create a new one.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson maybe a "clone this listing" option would suffice?

Comment: @Haney Andrew Brobston actually built that for his onboarding project, and ended up shipping a more polished version of it a couple of months ago. I haven't seen metrics on how big of an impact it's had.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for bringing this up, and I'm sorry that it’s been so long since our last update on this front. Reading through the previous discussion, it seems that there are a few ideas packed together here:

**1) Submitting updates to a previous application**

This comes up occasionally in feedback. The main complication here is that applications can be managed in several different ways depending on the employer’s set up. Some manage applications entirely within our employer-facing portal, but most rely on their internal applicant tracking systems or reviewing applications via email. When dealing with third-party systems or email, we often have no way of knowing when an application has been reviewed let alone updating a previously submitted application.

Upon investigating this further, we learned that the most common reason users asked for this feature was because of a mistake made in the application. Hence, in 2018, we added the ability to “undo” an application for a brief period after submission.

As for the general use-case to re-submit an updated application, we decided not to support it in the foreseeable future.

---

**2) Companies recycling listings instead of closing & posting a new one**

Back in 2016, the majority of employers on the platform were charged per published listing. We had a sizeable number of companies that were recycling listings (as described in the comments on the original question).

We’ve made a ton of changes to the platform since then. Today, almost all employers use reusable slots to publish their listings. We’ve made several UX improvements that make it easy for employers to close & publish new listings and clone existing listings, thus discouraging them from recycling an existing listing. Plus, using separate listings provides them with much clearer tracking & reporting.

As a result, we rarely see this issue come up anymore. If you’re still seeing cases where a listing was recycled (i.e. the whole listing was repurposed to be a different job), please flag it so we can investigate.

---

**3) Sort order**

By default, Jobs are sorted by match quality. This takes several factors into account, recency being only one of them.

However, if you choose to sort by “newest” jobs, we *do* take recently updated listings into account instead of just looking at the original publish date. This is because we actively work with our customers on improving listings based on performance and feedback, so poor quality listings often get updated.

---

**4) Better application management**

We definitely can do a better job with the application management experience. Filtering out jobs you’ve already applied to and being able to review previously submitted applications would be a good start. This is something we’ve spoken about and aim to address in 2019. However, I don’t have a firm timeline yet.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Your point #2 was the main issue that prompted this question.

Answer (score 5):

Whether and when to allow reapplications is one issue; the result list is another.

The job listings are dynamic. Just don't show any for which the current user (if any) can not apply, for whichever reason.

Comment: Take @ChrisMarisic answer - the job was updated to allow remote working but he was prevented from applying to the updated job as he'd already applied pre-update. This answer appears to suggest that not only should he not be able to apply but that he should not see the updated job because he cannot apply for it.

Comment: @MT0 No. This answer suggests that no matter what the reapplication rules are, the list should not show entries that can't be acted upon. That would be a waste of time. My answer does not make a statement about the cases in which reapplication should be possible, and explicitly says so.

Comment: @MT0 the position was always marked as allowing remote, they prioritized hiring local, they didn't earnestly consider the remote candidates until they were unable to fill local talent (which took them about a month to determine)